# How can i get all group list with kafka0.10.x

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

when i use kafka0.8.x，i can get all group list with zookeeper by path `/consumers/group_id`, because offsets will commit to zookeeper in 0.8.x.

But in version of 0.10.x, offsets commited to kafka broker like a path `/brokers/topics/__consumer_offsets` and path `/consumers` in zookeeper has nothing. so I can not get consumer group list by zookeeper.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To list all consumer groups across all topics:

```
 bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server broker1:9092 --list
```

To view offsets for the consumer group:

```
 bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server broker1:9092 --describe --group test-consumer-group
```

See [Managing Consumer Groups](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_consumer_group) for detailed information.

Comment: Yes, it can use shell command to get group list.But any other way to get group info by API? When I get group list from zookeeper, I can get the node info to show group create time, update time,how many consumers in this group......There are so many infos I can get from zookeeper, however when offset commit to brokers the info less than before,and I want to know the structure of group and consumers, there are any documents for it?

Comment: Well, no official documents offered for the detailed information about how to get these part of data using a programmatically way, but you could try AdminClient.describeGroup or AdminClient.describeConsumerGroup which both receive the group id as the only parameter. The return types are GroupSummary and List[GroupSummary] respectively. GroupSummary encapsulates most of the information you want.